# Why does my absolute react imports in VS Code automatically convert to relative from time to time?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm developing a React application in VS Code and uses absolute imports. However, I had many cases where some 43 or more files containing absolute imports automatically changes to relative imports. Of course I can always close all those files without saving the changes and then they will go back to being absolute imports again but is there any reason why it happens? I don't have a certain clue as to why but might it have something to do with me copying a file?

Btw, I'm using typescript and has the ff in tsconfig

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"outDir": "build/dist",
"module": "esnext",
"target": "es5",
"lib": ["es6", "dom"],
"sourceMap": true,
"allowJs": true,
"jsx": "react",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"rootDir": "src",
// "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false, // default true
"noImplicitReturns": true,
"noImplicitThis": true,
"noImplicitAny": true,
"strictNullChecks": true,
"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
"noUnusedLocals": true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier` and
>   `typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier` settings specify the type
>   of path to use for imports.
>
> Valid values are:
>
> `"relative"` to the file location.
>
> `"non-relative"` based on the `baseUrl` configured in your `jsconfig.json / tsconfig.json`.
>
> `"auto"` to infer the shortest path type.

Comment: actually I want to use absolute imports instead and removing baseUrl only cause "Cannot find module errors"

Comment: edited the answer maby it is now helpfull @JohnStephen.19